# What is the name of the graph whose fundamental cycles contain its all vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to ask how to call the connected graph whose $each$ vertex is included by its $some$ fundamental cycles? Is there any connection with the notion "vertex cycle cover"?

Comment: Do you mean "the graph has a spanning tree such that _each_ fundamental cycle contains all vertices", or "the graph has a spanning tree such that _some_ fundamental cycle contains all vertices", or "the graph has a spanning tree such that each vertex is in some fundamental cycle"? Or do you mean to quantify differently over all spanning trees? Please clarify.

Comment: I would try to explain with the edges. My connected graph musn't contain such bridges whose two vertices doesn't occur in some fundamental cycles.

Comment: That's the same as requiring that each vertex is in some cycle (fundamental or not).

Comment: ... which is true if every vertex has at least one non-bridge edge.

Comment: I don't know, if I could explain my problem. I would like to require nothing else, but my connected graph musn't contain bridges, except that it links two cycles.

Comment: You mention [vertex cycle cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover) yourself, and your condition is exactly that the graph has a vertex cycle cover.

Comment: Can these graphs be called e.g. "vertex cycle covered graph"?